# С клавиатуры вводится три целых числа X, Y, Z. Определить являются ли эти числа тройкой Пифагора. Изначально неизвестно какое из чисел гипотенуза

Tags: java

```
// Подскажите пж по задаче, не очень понимаю теорему пифагора, всё что накидал:

public class Task5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = requestNumber();
    int y = requestNumber();
    int z = requestNumber();    
    }
    static int requestNumber() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: *не очень понимаю теорему пифагора* Найдите и прочитайте её формулировку. *всё что накидал* Это никак не относится к решаемой задаче. *Изначально неизвестно какое из чисел гипотенуза* Есссно наибольшее...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пифаго́рова тро́йка — упорядоченный набор из трёх натуральных чисел 
(x, y, z), удовлетворяющих следующему однородному квадратному уравнению:

```
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
```

Пример:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.Math.pow;

public class Task5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // создаем массив, чтобы удобнее потом отсортировать
        int[] numbers = new int[3];
        numbers[0] = requestNumber();
        numbers[1] = requestNumber();
        numbers[2] = requestNumber();

        // с начала нужно отсортировать эти числа (x, y, z)
        // в порядке возрастания
        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        // теперь проверяем являются ли эти числа тройкой Пифагора
        // по формуле: x^2 + y^2 = z^2
        // и выводим ответ
        if ((pow(numbers[0], 2) + pow(numbers[1], 2)) == pow(numbers[2], 2)) {
            System.out.println("Эти числа являются тройкой Пифагора");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Эти числа не являются тройкой Пифагора");
        }
    }

    static int requestNumber() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

P.S. обратите внимание, введенные числа нужно отсортировать как показано на примере выше.

Comment: Есть ещё такой вариат проверки в Java: if (Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2) == Math.pow(z,2))

Comment: Я немного ошибся, сейчас быстро исправлю

Comment: Работает, только если гипотенуза вводится последней, что по условиям не гарантировано.

Comment: Исправил! Забыл отсортировать, извините.

Comment: @Эникейщик, уберите свой дизлайк пожалуйста.

Comment: @SherzodMamadaliev как вы узнали кто поставил диз ?

Comment: @Эникейщик, чутье.